# Prisma data design for reading application

Tags: database-design, schema, prisma

I am building a web application that allows you save books to a reading list, mark them as read when you are done. You can also post a review on a particular book. I have a prisma schema that has three tables. User, book and comment. Users can have many books, and books can have many users (i.e two users can pick the same book). Comments are associated with one book and one user. I have unique ids for each table, but I need to "link" the User, Book and Comment tables. I am linking the User table (kindeId) to the Book table (userId), the User table (kindeId) to the Comment table (commenter), and the Book table (isbn) to the Comment table (commentedBook). At the moment the isbn field in the Book table is "unique" which doesn't work because I would need there to be multiple records of that isbn for each user that is associated with it. Prisma gives me this error (Error parsing attribute "@relation": The argument `references` must refer to a unique criterion in the related model. Consider adding an `@unique` attribute to the field `isbn` in the model `Book`.) when I remove it from the isbn field.

```
`generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  kindeId   String  @unique
  firstName String   
  lastName  String    
  joined    DateTime @default(now())

  book      Book[]

  comments  Comment[]
  
}

model Book {
  id         String   @id @default(cuid())
  isbn       String   @unique
  title      String   
  author     String   
  category   String   
  description String?
  thumbnail  String?   
  userId    String   // This field references kindeId in the User model
  addedDate DateTime @default(now())
  pageCount  Int?
  isRead     Boolean  @default(false)

  user       User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [kindeId], onDelete: Cascade)

  comments   Comment[]
}

model Comment {
  commentId    String   @id @default(cuid())
  commenter    String   // This field references kindeId in the User model
  comment      String
  commentedBook String   // This field references isbn in the Book model
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())

  user         User     @relation(fields: [commenter], references: [kindeId])


  book         Book     @relation(fields: [commentedBook], references: [isbn])


}`
```

I am thinking that perhaps I would need to make some type of "junction table" between User and Book considering that there is a many-to-many relationship. If I did that I would have one record of each book in the Book table, one record of each user in the User table, and then I could link them in the junction table by the "isbn" and "kindeId". But I also have an isRead field in the book table that denotes whether the user has read the book or not. This is defaulted to false but would change to true if the user chose to do so. I am struggling to figure out how I could incorporate this. Any help most welcome. Many thanks in advance!